# Establishing an AP on Raspberry pi

Tags: wifi, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to setup an access point, using Raling RT5370 USB Dongle on a Debian system, I followed the following [tutorial](http://thenewbieblog.wordpress.com/2012/05/01/wifi-hotspot-setup-on-ubuntu/), until "Internet connection Sharing.", I don't want to share internet, so I skip this step. After the reboot I can see the AP, but I can't connect, it seams I can't get an IP address, how can I debug on raspberry to see what's happening or where did I made the mistake?

This is my dhcpd.conf file content:

```
ddns-update-style none;

subnet 10.10.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
        range 10.10.0.2 10.10.0.16;
        option domain-name-servers 8.8.4.4, 208.67.222.222;
        option routers 10.10.0.1;
}
```

The system log:

```
Aug 11 20:47:46 raspberrypi dhcpd: Wrote 0 leases to leases file.
Aug 11 20:47:46 raspberrypi dhcpd: 
Aug 11 20:47:46 raspberrypi dhcpd: No subnet declaration for wlan0 (no IPv4 addresses).
Aug 11 20:47:46 raspberrypi dhcpd: ** Ignoring requests on wlan0.  If this is not what
Aug 11 20:47:46 raspberrypi dhcpd:    you want, please write a subnet declaration
Aug 11 20:47:46 raspberrypi dhcpd:    in your dhcpd.conf file for the network segment
Aug 11 20:47:46 raspberrypi dhcpd:    to which interface wlan0 is attached. **
Aug 11 20:47:46 raspberrypi dhcpd: 
Aug 11 20:47:46 raspberrypi dhcpd: 
Aug 11 20:47:46 raspberrypi dhcpd: Not configured to listen on any interfaces!
```

sytemlog:

```
Aug 11 21:00:23 raspberrypi hostapd: wlan0: STA 5c:0a:5b:24:43:d9 IEEE 802.11: disassociated
Aug 11 21:00:23 raspberrypi hostapd: wlan0: STA 5c:0a:5b:24:43:d9 IEEE 802.11: disassociated
Aug 11 21:00:26 raspberrypi hostapd: wlan0: STA 5c:0a:5b:24:43:d9 IEEE 802.11: authenticated
Aug 11 21:00:26 raspberrypi hostapd: wlan0: STA 5c:0a:5b:24:43:d9 IEEE 802.11: associated (aid 1)
Aug 11 21:00:26 raspberrypi kernel: [  123.878201] BUG: scheduling while atomic: hostapd/1358/0x00000002
Aug 11 21:00:26 raspberrypi kernel: [  123.878227] Modules linked in: aes_generic 8021q garp stp llc snd_bcm2835 snd_pcm snd_seq snd_timer snd_seq_device snd snd_page_alloc arc4 rt2800usb rt2800lib crc_ccitt rt2x00usb rt2x00lib mac80211 cfg80211
Aug 11 21:00:26 raspberrypi kernel: [  123.878515] [<c00153d4>] (unwind_backtrace+0x0/0xfc) from [<c03f9598>] (dump_stack+0x20/0x24)
Aug 11 21:00:26 raspberrypi kernel: [  123.878580] [<c03f9598>] (dump_stack+0x20/0x24) from [<c00216d0>] (__schedule_bug+0x74/0x80)
Aug 11 21:00:26 raspberrypi kernel: [  123.878621] [<c00216d0>] (__schedule_bug+0x74/0x80) from [<c03f9e00>] (__schedule+0x568/0x670)
Aug 11 21:00:26 raspberrypi kernel: [  123.878669] [<c03f9e00>] (__schedule+0x568/0x670) from [<c03fa4cc>] (schedule+0x58/0x70)
Aug 11 21:00:26 raspberrypi kernel: [  123.878708] [<c03fa4cc>] (schedule+0x58/0x70) from [<c03fa9b4>] (schedule_timeout+0x1a0/0x34c)
Aug 11 21:00:26 raspberrypi kernel: [  123.878745] [<c03fa9b4>] (schedule_timeout+0x1a0/0x34c) from [<c03fa2c4>] (wait_for_common+0xf0/0x1c4)
Aug 11 21:00:26 raspberrypi kernel: [  123.878793] [<c03fa2c4>] (wait_for_common+0xf0/0x1c4) from [<c03fa44c>] (wait_for_completion_timeout+0x1c/0x20)
Aug 11 21:00:26 raspberrypi kernel: [  123.878842] [<c03fa44c>] (wait_for_completion_timeout+0x1c/0x20) from [<c02dd2f4>] (usb_start_wait_urb+0xac/0xd4)
Aug 11 21:00:26 raspberrypi kernel: [  123.878884] [<c02dd2f4>] (usb_start_wait_urb+0xac/0xd4) from [<c02dd538>] (usb_control_msg+0xd4/0xf8)
Aug 11 21:00:26 raspberrypi kernel: [  123.878962] [<c02dd538>] (usb_control_msg+0xd4/0xf8) from [<bf09eddc>] (rt2x00usb_vendor_request+0xc0/0x144 [rt2x00usb])
Aug 11 21:00:26 raspberrypi kernel: [  123.879030] [<bf09eddc>] (rt2x00usb_vendor_request+0xc0/0x144 [rt2x00usb]) from [<bf09ef18>] (rt2x00usb_vendor_req_buff_lock+0x70/0x120 [rt2x00usb])
Aug 11 21:00:26 raspberrypi kernel: [  123.879105] [<bf09ef18>] (rt2x00usb_vendor_req_buff_lock+0x70/0x120 [rt2x00usb]) from [<bf09f148>] (rt2x00usb_vendor_request_buff+0x78/0xbc [rt2x00usb])
Aug 11 21:00:26 raspberrypi kernel: [  123.879182] [<bf09f148>] (rt2x00usb_vendor_request_buff+0x78/0xbc [rt2x00usb]) from [<bf0bc1b4>] (rt2x00usb_register_multiread+0x48/0x50 [rt2800usb])
Aug 11 21:00:26 raspberrypi kernel: [  123.879274] [<bf0bc1b4>] (rt2x00usb_register_multiread+0x48/0x50 [rt2800usb]) from [<bf0ab014>] (rt2800_get_tkip_seq+0x50/0x80 [rt2800lib])
Aug 11 21:00:26 raspberrypi kernel: [  123.879588] [<bf0ab014>] (rt2800_get_tkip_seq+0x50/0x80 [rt2800lib]) from [<bf0528d8>] (ieee80211_get_key+0x1a8/0x1f8 [mac80211])
Aug 11 21:00:26 raspberrypi kernel: [  123.879964] [<bf0528d8>] (ieee80211_get_key+0x1a8/0x1f8 [mac80211]) from [<bf00a908>] (nl80211_get_key+0x288/0x328 [cfg80211])
Aug 11 21:00:26 raspberrypi kernel: [  123.880130] [<bf00a908>] (nl80211_get_key+0x288/0x328 [cfg80211]) from [<c036c2bc>] (genl_rcv_msg+0x1f0/0x23c)
Aug 11 21:00:26 raspberrypi kernel: [  123.880183] [<c036c2bc>] (genl_rcv_msg+0x1f0/0x23c) from [<c036b568>] (netlink_rcv_skb+0xcc/0xe8)
Aug 11 21:00:26 raspberrypi kernel: [  123.880219] [<c036b568>] (netlink_rcv_skb+0xcc/0xe8) from [<c036c0c0>] (genl_rcv+0x28/0x34)
Aug 11 21:00:26 raspberrypi kernel: [  123.880254] [<c036c0c0>] (genl_rcv+0x28/0x34) from [<c036ae78>] (netlink_unicast+0x2c8/0x320)
Aug 11 21:00:26 raspberrypi kernel: [  123.880297] [<c036ae78>] (netlink_unicast+0x2c8/0x320) from [<c036b0e0>] (netlink_sendmsg+0x210/0x328)
Aug 11 21:00:26 raspberrypi kernel: [  123.880341] [<c036b0e0>] (netlink_sendmsg+0x210/0x328) from [<c0336cf0>] (sock_sendmsg+0xb0/0xd0)
Aug 11 21:00:26 raspberrypi kernel: [  123.880380] [<c0336cf0>] (sock_sendmsg+0xb0/0xd0) from [<c033713c>] (__sys_sendmsg+0x318/0x338)
Aug 11 21:00:26 raspberrypi kernel: [  123.880428] [<c033713c>] (__sys_sendmsg+0x318/0x338) from [<c0338c38>] (sys_sendmsg+0x4c/0x78)
Aug 11 21:00:26 raspberrypi kernel: [  123.880475] [<c0338c38>] (sys_sendmsg+0x4c/0x78) from [<c000e140>] (ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x48)
Aug 11 21:00:26 raspberrypi hostapd: wlan0: STA 5c:0a:5b:24:43:d9 RADIUS: starting accounting session 5026C775-00000001
Aug 11 21:00:26 raspberrypi hostapd: wlan0: STA 5c:0a:5b:24:43:d9 WPA: pairwise key handshake completed (RSN)
```

hostapd.conf

```
interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211
ssid=quadcopter
channel=1
hw_mode=g
auth_algs=1
wpa=3
wpa_passphrase=1234567890
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP CCMP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

Interface

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
 address 10.10.0.1
 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

ifconfig

```
mon.wlan0 Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-0F-53-B1-13-41-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1812 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:545248 (532.4 KiB)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0f:53:b1:13:41  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:11 errors:0 dropped:5 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1915 (1.8 KiB)  TX bytes:1698 (1.6 KiB)
```

Do I have to setup something else, because I can see the AP but I can't connect.
I just tested on Ubuntu 12.04 and it's working, I did the same configuration on the Raspberry Pi, without success

Comment: Cross-posted on [Raspberry Pi](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/1549/); closing here (please [don't cross-post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/faq#cross-posting))